# How to make docker-compose volume as optional or disable volume using flag

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to set a flag in my docker-compose file, whether If I dont need my db volume will not persistent outside container, But I still want an entry for volume, If my db  is small then I dont want it to persistent outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two docker-compose.yml files.

1. docker-compose.yml
2. docker-compose.small.yml

Overwrite the volume section in Number #2 and run:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.small.yml up -d
```

For more Background: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Comment: What would be the contents of `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.small.yml`? If `docker-compose.yml` contains a `services/app/volumes` entry, it can not be removed in `docker-compose.small.yml`: "Entries for volumes and devices are merged using the mount path in the container:" ([extends](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/))

Answer (score 5):

Volumes can't be optional but there's a workaround using a single docker-compose file:

```
    volumes:
      - ${DUMMY_MOUNT:-.:/app}
```

This will do a usual mount by default: `.:/app` but you can set the `DUMMY_MOUNT` variable to avoid it. E.g. `DUMMY_MOUNT=.:/dummy docker-compose up`.